# How to have the best solution for this equation $4\sqrt{x^5}-10x^2-(5-8\sqrt{x})x+\sqrt{x}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to have the best solution for this equation $4\sqrt{x^5}-10x^2-(5-8\sqrt{x})x+\sqrt{x}=0$ (1)

I set $t=\sqrt{x}$
and $(1) \Leftrightarrow t(4t^4-10t^3-5t^2+8t+1)=0$

So It's difficult :(

Thank all!

Comment: yes, because equation $4t^4-10t^3-5t^2+8t+1=0$ too difficult to solve it!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't miscopied something or made a calculation error? Rational root theorem quickly shows that that quartic has no rational roots, which would indeed make it difficult to factor...

Comment: as @AWertheim said, (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4t%5E4%E2%88%9210t%5E3%E2%88%925t%5E2%2B8t%2B1%3D0) gives pretty ugly results

Comment: corrected solutions as @Amzoti pointed out: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4t%5E4%E2%88%9210t%5E3%2B8t%5E2%E2%88%925t%2B1%3D0)

Comment: Of course, if you already know the roots then you can easily factor the expression. Your expression factors as $t(2t^2-4t+1)(2t^2-t+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine.

You have a slight issue (recall the x needs to be distributed to all terms) and should have gotten:

$$t(4t^4-10t^3+8t^2-5t+1)=0$$

Now, all you need to do is use your favorite root finding algorithm or the [*Quartic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function).

Here is a plot of the fourth order equation:

[image]

You should get the roots:

$$t = 0, 1\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2}}$$

The other two are complex roots.

Recall, you need to square the result you get to get back the x-values and there are three real ones.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: You copied it wrongly, it is $4t^4−10t^3−5t^2+8t+1$

Comment: Nevermind, i assumed his solution was right

Comment: Nice encouragement, "steering", link, and graphic, all in one! +1

Comment: @TongCongDanh: Did this answer resolve your issues? Regards